# How to convert this echo? using this approach

Tags: php, mysql, echo

how to convert this?

```
 <td><a style="font weight: 700; font-size:1.2em;" href="preview.php?   app_id=<?php echo $row['app_id']; ?>name=<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">PRINT</a> <!-- <a href="#" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="delbutton" title="Click To Delete">Delete</a> --></td>
```

into this?

```
echo '<td>' . $row['curdate'] . '</td>'
```

here's the full code

```
   <tr class="success">
              <td><?php echo $row['app_id']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['addr']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['contact']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['curdate']; ?></td>
              <td><a style="font weight: 700; font-size:1.2em;" href="preview.php?   app_id=<?php echo $row['app_id']; ?>name=<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">PRINT</a> <!-- <a href="#" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="delbutton" title="Click To Delete">Delete</a> --></td>
              </tr>
```

into this?

```
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['app_id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['addr'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['contact'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['curdate'] . '</td>';
    echo 'PRINT CODE GOES HERE</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
$html = '<tr class="success">
              <td>'. $row['app_id'].'</td>
              <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
              <td>'.$row['addr'].'</td>
              <td>'.$row['contact'].'</td>
              <td>'.$row['curdate'].'</td>
              <td><a style="font weight: 700; font-size:1.2em;" href="preview.php?app_id='.$row['app_id'].'name='.$row['name'].'">PRINT</a> <!-- <a href="#" id="'.$row['id'].'" class="delbutton" title="Click To Delete">Delete</a> --></td>
              </tr>';

              echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
echo '<tr class="success">
              <td>'. $row['app_id'].'</td>
              <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
              <td>'.$row['addr'].'</td>
              <td>'.$row['contact'].'</td>
              <td>'.$row['curdate'].'</td>
              <td><a style="font weight: 700; font-size:1.2em;" href="preview.php?app_id='.$row['app_id'].'&name='.$row['name'].'">PRINT</a> </td>
              </tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

once again, so "many ways to skin a cat"! (it's a Welsh idiom!)

currently I prefer this:

```
echo <<<HTML
    <tr class="success">
        <td>{$row['app_id']}</td>
        <td>{$row['name']}</td>
        <td>{$row['addr']}</td>
        <td>{$row['contact']}</td>
        <td>{$row['curdate']}</td>
        <td><a style="font weight: 700; font-size:1.2em;" href="preview.php?app_id={$row['app_id']}&name={$row['name']}">PRINT</a> <!-- <a href="#" id="{echo $row['id']}" class="delbutton" title="Click To Delete">Delete</a> --></td>
    </tr>
HTML;
```

this way you don't have to worry about: dropping in and out of php (`<?php`, `?>`); multiple `echo` statements; string concatenation with `'.` and `.'`; escaping any `'` or `"` depending on which you used for your `echo`.